# How to execute bash script by zabbix agent using sudo?

Tags: sudo, zabbix, sudoers

OS Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
I did everything as usual. Using visudo I allowed the zabbix user to execute the command:

```
zabbix ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/root/market-report/docker-compose_restart zabbix-agent2
```

In the config of the zabbix agent itself, I registered permission to execute system commands:

```
# nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.conf
AllowKey=system.run[*]
```

Does not work. Gives an error:

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
```

Okay, I'll add:

```
# visudo
Defaults:zabbix !requiretty
```

Does not work.
Then I just try to execute the script on the host from this user:

```
# sudo -u zabbix sudo /root/market-report/docker-compose_restart
```

No way...

```
[sudo] password for zabbix:
```

What else does he need?
How I may executing script throught sudo without password

Comment: `What else does he need?` `sudo: a password is required` A password.

Comment: You probably already guessed that I want to execute the script without a password. Everything is OK on another host - the script be executing without problems when performing the above actions

Comment: i did not. then configure sudo not to require password or do noy use sudo or use sudo -S. i do not understand

Comment: I configured it to work without a password. In the first post I indicated how I set it up. It works on another host. Not on this one. What did I do wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally made easier. Moved the script to another folder and gave the owner to user zabbix